# Display HTML elements via PHP Validation

Tags: php

after i tried everything i could, i am not able to make that a conditional shows me some div if it's true or false in MySQL. 
For example i have 3 divs:

```
<div id="page1">
<form action="validation.php" method="post">
           <input class="login" type="text" name="user" value=" Usuario">
           <br><br>
           <input id="submit-form" type="submit" value="ENTRAR">
           <br><br>
        </form> 
</div> //login page with form
<div id="page2" style="display: none" ></div> //main page
<div id="page3" style="display: none" ></div> //access denied
```

And my PHP file:

```
<?php

include("calendar/config.php");

global $iver;
$mydb= "MYDB";
global $user;
$user = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['user']);
global $page1;
$page1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['page1']);
global $page2;
$page2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['page2']);
global $page3;
$page3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['page3']);
global $db;
$db = mysqli_select_db($connection, $mydb) or die("Error al conectarse a la Base de datos: " . mysqli_error($connection));

function LoginAccess($connection, $user) {
        session_start();
        $query = "SELECT * FROM username where user = '".$user."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        if ($row) {
            echo $page2;
        }else{
            echo $page3;
        }

}

LoginAccess($connection, $user);


?>
```

I tried JS and AJAX also, but there's something i'm missing.
I will appreciate you teach me how to do it. It's a validation for myself. Thanksss

PD: config.php has the $connection values and it's working!!! BTW.

Comment: Try to change `id` to `name` on your input elements.

Comment: Tried that already!!!

Comment: Also post data works with input elements. You try to send div's?

Comment: Yes for example, i hide div 2 and div 3. But the form is into div 1. What I want is to display div 2 if user exists in db. The above code works with echo, print or another outputs, but have no idea how to render divs or if i can use JS inside the PHP file to display that. Tried JS but it only prints in the DOM, does not run the JS function.

Comment: Yeah but your post data is empty because there is no input element with the name `page1` (or any of the others)

Comment: Tried with `<form action="validation.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="page2" value="page2">`

Comment: An AJAX call to PHP could be a solution??? I'm working with MySQL.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167118/discussion-between-mark-baijens-and-homero).

Comment: I moved your solution to a community wiki answer.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

I had to use this code:

```
$(function(){
    $('#validation').on("submit",function(e){
        console.log($(this).serialize());
        $.ajax({
            url:'validation.php',
            type : 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data) {              
                    if (data == true){
                        $('#page1').hide();
                        $('#page2').show(); 
                    }else{
                        $('#page1').hide();
                        $('#page3').show();
                    }   
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
               console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
        })
        e.preventDefault();
    })
```

what means that data var returns the value true or false depending on the PHP variable.

I had to use `echo json_encode($check);`